# Firebase Get Notification data on tap

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I  was firebase console to send notifications. It sends notifications to system tray directly. I want to get payload from them when user taps on them.

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification
>   messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the
>   app launcher by default.
>
> This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload
>   (and all messages sent from the Notifications console). In these
>   cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and
>   the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your
>   launcher Activity.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience

I am able to get notifications that I sent from console
How do I get notification payload from extra of my intent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dumped extras bundle and found the answer.

These are they keys that I was looking for:

google.sent_time (long) 
from (string) 
google.message_id (String)
collapse_key (String)

Apart from these you can directly use the keys that you used for custom data (while sending message).

when we fire messages from firebase console, I think only custom data that we sent along can be received from extra's intent. Title,message etc I cannot retrieved from here

#### Update

As also observed by others, I don't think it is possible to extract title and message from extras intent. I found a workarond by passing them again with a separate key. Some code how to extract data from extras intent is

```
Bundle Extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
public static String Content_KEY = "NotificationContent"; //alterative to message
String Content = Extras.getString(Content_KEY);
```

I don't remember exact names, but there are 2 modes to send a message.

1. First mode is what firebase console uses. It sends messages directly

   1. To system tray if in background (as a notification)
   2. To onMessageReceived if in in foreground.

You will have to handle both, I ended up by sending notification from my app itself to system tray if I got it in onMessageReceived so that I could manage them from same code that handles extras intent in main activity.

You will also loose data if notification is lost.

2. Send message directly from a server or app to firebase server. I think message will always be sent to onMessageReceived, saving all the pain of sending message again as separate key and problem of loosing data if notification is removed. But here you will have to setup your own notification app / server

Comment: when user press on push notification then how we can get push notification message in Activity with firebase sdk. ?

Comment: I couldn't retrieve the message as it was not found in extras intent, I sent it a copy of it in another key such as myMessage

Comment: OK yourkey is under Notification object right ? and if possible can you share a code here so i can review it.

Comment: And i am not able get key when app is in background of killed.

Answer (score 2):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;


public class FirebaseDataReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

private final String TAG = "FirebaseDataReceiver";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

String dataBundle intent.getExtras().getString("gcm.notification.message");

}
}


<receiver
        android:name="PACKAGENAME.FirebaseDataReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This may help us

Comment: Something to keep in mind: "This class was deprecated in API level 26.1.0."
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver